# Locator strategy for list view elements in Android app

Tags: appium, android, android-automation

I am automating a calendar feature in an Android app using Appium. The developers have set content-desc for us to be used as accessibility ids. For simple elements like buttons it works like a charm. But we have a problem automating the main calendar view which actually is a two dimensional list view, where multiple events are present under weekdays for a week view.

Till now we were having unique accessibility ids for each day and event using indexes so we had as an example here,

For days:

> **content desc** - day_[index] , where index is an integer from 1 to 7

And for each day the events:

> **content desc** - event_[day index]_[event index]

All was going perfectly but then we had to make the App usable for voice over so the above complex programming content-desc values had to be replaced with user friendly texts. Now, my problem is how and which Android locators are best to give our values?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're looking for.  Are you saying that you'd like locators like "...one..." "...two..." or "...Monday..." "...Tuesday..." etc?  What do you mean by "voice-over?"

Comment: Please add the page source.  Giving advice blind is never very helpful.

Comment: He is asking 1) which element locator strategy should he recommend to his team? And 2) as a sub-text, why is the Appium community promoting co-opting AccessibilityID for testing when that attribute's legitimate purpose is for text-to-voice assistive technology, not testing?

Comment: I am asking the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923738/multilingual-mobile-app-using-accessibilityids-for-appium-bad-recipe